# order of "styled-components" and "sass" styles injected to a "react" index page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, styled-components, html-webpack-plugin

In our project we are using the combination of `sass` and `styled-components`! (we had sass from early days and now step by step moving toward just styled-components)
And our project has a quite typical stack (`react`, `typescript`, `webpack` and ...)

I recently updated our styled-components to version `5.0.1` and started to face a weird issue.

In `mode: "development"`, wen I run the project, the first time page is opened in browser, all is ok... but after a refresh, my styles start overriding each other in a wrong order.

In `mode: "production"`, of course it's broken from the beginning!

I've noticed that it happens because of the wrong placement of injected `<style />` by `styled-components`

When it's correct, the order looks like this (`<style />` is somehow in between):

[image]

but when I refresh, it changes to this (goes all the way down after all other `<link />`s and `<script />`s):

[image]

I've tried variant ways to have it working, but no success... finally by downgrading styled-component to `4.4.1`, the issue is fixed and order is correct:

[image]

Here is also my webpack config for `.sass` files, which is again quite standard

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.sass$/i,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            {
                 loader: "postcss-loader",
                 options: {
                    ident: "postcss",
                    plugins: [require("autoprefixer")()],
                 },
             },
             "sass-loader",
        ],
    },
]
```

I was not sure if it can be handled properly in my code or just need to file an issue / question in styled-components github page... so asking it here first :)

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: not yet @attrib! still keeping it in a version that works... meantime every now and then I check this post to see if there is any update there: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3070